# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value prepareForSegue

Tags: swift, xcode

I am beginner in swift and working on one project where I am using collectionView. From collectionView, I want to transfer some values to details view but I am getting the above mentioned error. Values are not nil but somehow, it is giving this error while performing segue. Anybody help me, I am badly stuck here.

```
//In my CollectionView Controller.
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

if(segue.identifier == "DetailsView")
    {
        if let vc:DetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController
            {
                vc.details.text = self.description
                vc.line.text = self.subText
                vc.startTime.text = self.formatted_time
        }
}
}

//DetailsViewController
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var startTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var line: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var details: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()  
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically means your `IBOutlets` are not yet initialised.

You should set strings and then in the `viewDidLoad` set you labels.
So to sum up:

1. Add string properties in your `DetailsViewController`
2. Set these string properties in your `preparForsegue` function
3. in the `viewDidLoad` of your `DetailsViewController`, set your labels

Your code should look like something like this :

```
//In my CollectionView Controller.
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "DetailsView")
    {
        if let vc:DetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController
        {
            vc.detailsString = self.description
            vc.lineString = self.subText
            vc.startTimeString = self.formatted_time
        }
    }
}

//DetailsViewController
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var startTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var line: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var details: UILabel!

    var startTimeString: String?
    var lineString: String?
    var detailsString: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        startTime.text = tmpStartTimeString
        line.text = tmpLineString
        details.text = tmpDetailsString

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Double check my code, I've wrote it very quickly ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `IBOutlets` in a destination view controller aren't set until some time after `prepareForSegue` finishes

In `DetailsViewController`, add three instance variables:

```
var startTime: String?
var line: String?
var details: String?
```

Then in `prepareForSegue`, set those three values:

```
vc.details = self.description
vc.line = self.subText
vc.startTime = self.formatted_time
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` of `DetailsViewController`

```
detailsLabel.text = self.details
lineLabel.text = self.line
startTimeLabel.text = self.startTime
```

Answer (score 0):

As the two answer above are point out when you create an instance of a `UIViewController` like for example in the `prepareForSegue` when you call `segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController` this not mean that the `@IBOutlet`'s are injected or initialized yet. The `@IBOutlet`'s are initialized when the view is fully loaded, so you can do two of the following options:

1. Create variables in your `UIViewController` in which you can save the values after the init of the `UIViewController` in the `prepareForSegue` and then in the `viewDidLoad()` of the another `UIViewController` you set the values for the `@IBOutlet`'s.
2. Another option is call the `view` (e.g `let _ = vc.view`) property when you create the instance of the `UIViewController`, in this way you can force the view to load load fully and you can set your `@IBOutlet`'s from the `prepareForSegue`.

I hope this help you.